# change admin to desktop user and the

Tags: permissions, user-management

desktop-user to admin. what will happen?
because i am new to linux (lubuntu) and i have forgotten to create a new desktop user to work with, now i have a good setup with a electrum wallet ect. and i found it would be easy for me if i could just change the 2 users user-roles.

will all work fine if i do this? its not reversable says the system-popup windwow and i have no lust for a broken file-system!
sorry for this question, but i am still learning things in Linux.
thanks in advance for some tips how to handel this purpose...

Comment: You mean activating root user?

Comment: @Arun no, just with the gui, the user-roles , where you could click the checkbox for admin or desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you do not enter your password for root access you will be fine. You will work just like a normal desktop user even if you had the permission to become administrator when needed.

Only after you had chosen tasks that need such  administrator permissions (such as e.g. installing or removing software) you will be asked for the "root" password (which is your login password of course). You will then become an admin for this very task only.

More advanced users can also become Root temporarily by preceding a terminal command with `sudo`.

There is no need to change the account to a mere desktop user account. In fact **it can even be dangerous to do so** if you by accident ended up with no administrator account. So before you changed you account to a desktop user account, make triple sure you had created another administrator account before you proceed.

Comment: So if i understand you rigth, it is ok to use my current ubuntu-pc with a single (admin) user account? no need to add another user (desktop) anyway if i'm the only user of the this pc, correct? thank you!

Comment: Yeah that's correct. Most people do it like that. What I mostly do in addition is to  add a **second admin** account to be able to repair stuff in case I can't log in to my own account.